# C: conditional expressions with multiple operators

Tags: c, operators

In C, is something like this legal?

```
if (0<=x<=y<=y+1) then ...
```

Or do I have to separate it with &&'s and ||'s and brackets?

Comment: I Highly recommend that you use parenthesis to show your intent.  You might have to modify the code some day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's legal but probably doesn't do what you expect.  It is treated as if you'd written:

```
if (((0 <= x) <= y) <= y+1)
```

The `(0 <= x)` evaluates to 0 or 1; the 0 or 1 is compared with `y`, yielding another 0 or 1 result; this is compared with `y+1`, yielding the final 0 or 1 used to control the `if` statement.

If you are aiming to ensure that `x` is not smaller than zero or bigger than `y`, and also to ensure that `y` is not bigger than `y+1`, then you'd write:

```
if (0 <= x && x <= y && y <= y+1)
```

I note that `y <= y+1` is usually true.  If `y` is an unsigned type and equal to the maximum value of that type, then `y+1` is 0.  If `y` is a signed type and equal to the maximum value of that type, then you invoke undefined behaviour by adding 1 to it.  If you're lucky, `y+1` will wrap to the maximum negative value for the signed type, but you can't rely on that (so maybe that makes it "if you're unlucky", because the bug won't necessarily show up before it causes major problems).

Comment: @Linuxios I don't think this type of syntax is terribly uncommon in more modern languages.  Python, for example, handles it just fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: sorry about the misinterpretation, and my apologies if it was seen as an assult.

Comment: @AaronDufour: to state my comment better, I think it's interesting that Python supports that. I wonder how the interpreter tells whether to interpret it that way or the old C way.

Comment: @Linuxios Chained comparisons are always interpreted this way (comparisons are [==, <, >, <=, >=, !=]).  You can get the C behavior by not having chained comparisons (i.e. `(0 < x) < 7` has no chained comparisons, since the chaining is broken by parens).

Answer (score 3):

It is legal (and defined; Google search term 'operator precedence'), but I don't think it will do what you expect or mean for it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that is not at all possible to do what you want, although it is legal C code. You have to use && or ||. The reason is that you are actually seeing if, for example, y is greater then or equal to a Boolean, which in C and C++ is usually just 0 and 1.

Comment: It is 'possible' in the sense that the syntax is legal.  It probably isn't what is wanted, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely legal but practically useless. You should build a proper expression with `&&` and/or `||`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an abuse of notation - even in a mathematical context and not strictly legal, even there. The only way to get the intended kind of meaning with <= still being a binary operator is (1) to lift the type of the operator from (ordinal,ordinal) → boolean to (boolean,ordinal), (boolean,ordinal) → (boolean,ordinal), with (B,Z) <= (B',Z') reinterpreted as (B && B' && Z <= Z', Z'), (2) to have an implicit conversion Z → (true, Z), and (3) to have another implicit conversion down to boolean (B, Z) → B.

You might be able to get something like that to happen in C++ with its tuple types, constructors and operator overloading.